# передать переменную из docker-composer в build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### Есть:

docker-composer.yml например такой

```
version: '2'
services:
   app:
     build: ./builder
     environment:
       BUILD_VAR: "intl xsl"
```

### Проблема:

Переменная **BUILD_VAR** не передается в **builder**. Как я понял по документации, эта переменная заполняется на момент запуска сервиса.

### Чего хочется:

Хочется использовать BUILD_VAR при построении образа, например передать туда дополнительные зависимости, и билдер их установит. Не совсем удобно создавать разные билдеры, если отличия небольшие

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Comment: был там, прошел успешно тест, и успешно забыл :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой предыдущий ответ был неверен - это возможно, но при наличии самого свежего docker-compose (1.6.0) и docker (1.10, на момент написания еще в предрелизном состоянии); у меня был конфликт версий при использовании 1.6.0 и 1.9.1, но, возможно, он вполне разрешаем; если нет, то потребуется подождать [до второго апреля](https://github.com/docker/docker/wiki) или воспользовать nightly-версией. Следующая конфигурация сервиса должна делать именно то, что требуется:

```
version: 2
services:
  ubuntu-based-service:
    build:
      context: docker-images/ubuntu-based-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        HELLO_WORLD_MESSAGE: Hey there world
```

https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2540#discussion-diff-49683771R98

Comment: странно, это докер умеет docker build --build-arg ... , а когда компосер использует, уже не хочет передавать аргументы. Причем указывать это ручками неудобно, удобно это делать в композере, но композер именно это и не хочет делать

Comment: @duhon воу, я даже не знал про build arg, отстал. Странно, что они его добавили.

Comment: @duhon обновил ответ